# A Database Error Occurred

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, localhost

> ```
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'username='xc'' in 'where clause'
>
>     SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` 
>     FROM (`users`) 
>     WHERE `username='xc'` 
>     AND `password='b587c9a76c9cd8dfc40a757616c1e47d'` 
>     LIMIT 1
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rpo\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330
> ```

Code :

```
function login($username,$password) {
    $this->db->select('id,username,password'); 
    $this->db->from('users'); 
    $this->db->where('username='."'".$username."'");
    $this->db->where('password='."'".MD5($password)."'"); 
    $this->db->limit(1); 
    $query=$this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()==1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {    
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Change \`username to \`username\` and \`password to \`password\`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
  SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` 
  FROM `users` 
  WHERE `username`='xc' 
  AND `password`='b587c9a76c9cd8dfc40a757616c1e47d' LIMIT 1
```

you should use backticks around the columns name not the whole sentence or whole where clause.

change your lines to those:

```
 $this->db->where('username' , $username );
 $this->db->where('password' , MD5($password) );
```

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"fv" AND `password` = "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33" LIMIT 1' at line 3

SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` FROM (`users`) WHERE `username=` "fv" AND `password` = "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33" LIMIT 1

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rpo\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: There is no such line in PHP / CI: `$this->db->where('username' = $username );`

Comment: To pass as string:
$this->db->where('username',$username);

$this->db->where('password', MD5($password));

Comment: yes i try..but $this->db->where('password' , MD5($password) '); more code (')

Comment: @user3234855 ohh sorry there was an extra quote, try now my edit

Answer (score 0):

you have an error, the position of ` in username condition
change this:

```
WHERE `username='xc'
```

to this:

```
WHERE `username`='xc'
```

complete code corrected:

```
SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` 
  FROM `users` 
  WHERE `username`='xc' 
  AND `password`='b587c9a76c9cd8dfc40a757616c1e47d' LIMIT 1
```

to change you codeigniter query try this:

```
$this->db->select('id,username,password');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('username= "'.$username.'"');
$this->db->where('password = "'.MD5($password).'"');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"fv" AND `password` = "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33" LIMIT 1' at line 3

SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` FROM (`users`) WHERE `username=` "fv" AND `password` = "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33" LIMIT 1

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rpo\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0):

DESCRIBE table_name //return table structure

Check column name and try again

Answer (score 0):

Fix in codeigniter method:

You can pass condition as string or array.

1. To pass as string:

> $this->db->where('username',$username);
>
> $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));

2.To pass as combined array

> $this->db->where(array('password'=>MD5($password),'username'=>$username));

Comment: thanks its solved. thanks :). but can u help me again?

Comment: @user3234855. If your problem solved, the accept the solution which helped you. Yes. What do you want next?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'parents' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\rpo\application\controllers\Home.php on line 7                                 class Home extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
{
 parents::__construct();
}

function index()
{
 if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
 {
  $session_data=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  $data['username']=$session_data['username'];
  $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
 }
 else
 {
  redirect('login','refresh');
 }

}
function logout()
{
 $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
 session_destroy();
 redirect('home','refresh');
}

Comment: I think you are loading model / library / helper in your home.php. It's name is mismatch or location is invalid or file may not exist.

Comment: come to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349816/fatal-error-class-parents-not-found-in-c-xampp-htdocs-rpo-application-contro

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select('id,username,password');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where("username ='$username'");
$this->db->where("password ='MD5($password)'");
$this->db->limit(1);
$query=$this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows()==1)
{
    return $query->result();
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"fv" AND password = "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33" LIMIT 1' at line 3 SELECT id, username, password FROM (users) WHERE username= "fv" AND password = "4a8a08f09d37b73795649038408b5f33" LIMIT 1 Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rpo\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 330