# Error in php file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, localhost

I'm receiving the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'parents' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\rpo\application\controllers\Home.php on line 7

Here is my code:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
           parents::__construct();
    }
    function index()
    {
       if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
       {
                $session_data=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['username']=$session_data['username'];
                $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
       }
       else
       {
                redirect('login','refresh');
       }
    }
   function logout()
   {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        session_destroy();
        redirect('home','refresh');
   }
```

line 7 is `parents::__construct();`

Answer (score 2):

"parents" should be "parent" in your constructor. parent is a keyword in PHP.

```
parent::__construct();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor This should be

```
function __construct()
{ 
  parent::__construct(); // Calling parent class constructors

}
```

not

```
parents::__construct();
```